# NoSuchElementException in java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

This code was compiled successfully but it is showing runtime error and exception as no such element in scanner class. After reading the testcase, it should take the input as string, but it is showing anexception.

```
public class CandidateCode 
{
      public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception
      {
            //Write code here
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            int testCase=sc.nextInt();
            while(testCase>0)
            {
                     //sc.next();
                     Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
                     String temp="";
                     String res="";
                     for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
                     {
                        if(temp.indexOf(str.charAt(i))==-1)
                           temp=temp+str.charAt(i);
                        else
                        {
                           res=res+str.charAt(i);
                         }
                      }
                      char min='z';
                      for(int j=0;j<res.length();j++)
                      {
                         if(res.charAt(j)<min)
                            min=res.charAt(j);
                      }
                      System.out.println(min);
                      testCase++;
              }
      }
  }
```

The compilation log error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
>        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
>          at CandidateCode.main(CandidateCode.java:19)

Comment: Why do you need `sc` and `scan`?

Comment: For any reviewers or the author: In my edit I accidentially deleted the `java` tag. If my edit will be approved, can somebody please re-add it?

Comment: Or maybe the other edit added it while I was editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoSuchElementException` is thrown from `Scanner.next()` if you are trying to read data when you have reached the end of the data stream.

Instead of:

```
sc.next();
...
```

use:

```
while(! sc.hasNext()) { }
sc.next();
...
```

`Scanner.hasNext()` checks if there is any more data to read, and the while loop waits until there is more data to read before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchElementException` will be thrown because you are trying to read the data from the input (Scanner) where data is reached to the end.

You have to read the input( Scanner ) by checking `hasNext()` is true or false

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `scanner.clear()` at the end of procedures or before use it again.